# UITabbar clinches text after presenting view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

I have a UISplitView and the master view contains a UITabBar at the bottom which I created in the Storyboard (the items of the UITabBar are also created in the Storyboard). The master view is also embedded in a UINavigationController) I present a new view in the master view like that:

```
AppDelegate* appDel = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UIViewController* viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ManageCategoryView"];
[appDel.window.rootViewController presentViewController:viewController
                                               animated:YES
                                             completion:^{}];
```

(I also tried `self.view presentViewController:...` but the same happens)

After presenting the view and closing it again the text in the UITabBar is clinched:

Before:
[a http://www.ld-host.de/uploads/images/bf4343f8d744a8270d76399a8781f55e.png](http://www.ld-host.de/uploads/images/bf4343f8d744a8270d76399a8781f55e.png)

After:
[a http://www.ld-host.de/uploads/images/2222ba5f5d469ec2ece04ac67bd00d4a.png](http://www.ld-host.de/uploads/images/2222ba5f5d469ec2ece04ac67bd00d4a.png)

This only happens on the iPhone. On the iPad the UITabBar stays the same.
Also, this doesn't happen when pushing a view to the UINavigationController.

Why does this happen and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out how to fix this problem.

I didn't add any constraints with Autolayout for the UITabBar and after I set a constraint so that it's at the bottom of the screen (distance to left, right and button set to 0) the UITabBar stays the same.

Still seems weird to me that missing constraints cause such a weird result, but now it works.